# How to find the database name using the table name?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I found the table name exist in my system, I used the following query;

```
select * from sys.tables where name = '%openpotab%';
```

But how can I find the database name using the table name?

thanks in advance,
Bhavesh

Comment: I suspect you mean LIKE not =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
select DB_NAME(DB_ID()), * from sys.tables where name LIKE '%openpotab%';
```

Comment: The first column is blank in the result set. It means there is no database name?

Comment: @Bob Please check now